# append item to dictionary list, kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a dictionary

```
q).test.dict:(`test1;`test2)!(1i;2i)
q).test.dict
test1| 1
test2| 2
```

and I need to append an item to one of the dictionary lists to get the following result:

```
q).test.dict
test1| 1
test2| 2 4i
```

However I am having trouble assigning to that dictionary list.

I have tried the following:

```
q).test.dict[`test2]:.test.dict[`test2],4i
'type
  [0]  .test.dict[`test2]:.test.dict[`test2],4i
```

And have tried other methods of assignment which also result in a type error.

I feel like im missing something quiet obvious here but cant seem to put my finger on it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you've initiated/defined the dictionary to have a uniform value (integer atoms) and so kdb expects/enforces the values to remain integer atoms. You can avoid this by creating a default entry (with say generic null `::`) to force the value to be a mixed list. Then you can append

```
.test.dict:(`;`test1;`test2)!(::;1i;2i)
```

Comment: is there a reason the following results in a type of int atom (-6h) and not a list of ints (6h)     q).test.dict:()!()
q).test.dict,:(enlist `test1)!enlist 5i
q).test.dict
test1| 5
q)type .test.dict[`test1]
-6h

Comment: Yes - because ```enlist[`test1]!enlist 5i``` is not a dictionary whose value is a list of ints. The `enlists` here are required just to form the 1-item dictionary but nevertheless the value is still an int atom. If you wanted a 1-item dictionary whose value is an list of ints then you'd need ```enlist[`test1]!enlist enlist 5i```

Answer (score 1):

If you instead define your dictionary like this

```
.test.dict:(`test1;`test2)!(enlist 1i;enlist 2i)
```

It will work. The problem is, the value of your dictionary is a list of integers, not a list of lists of integers.